# There is no nonunit $b\neq 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ satisfying $\forall a\in \Bbb{Z}$, $\exists q, r\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, $a=bq+r$, where $r=0$ or $r$ unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Prove that 
there is no nonunit $b\neq 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ satisfying that 
for all $a\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, 
there exists $q, r\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, 
such that $a=bq+r$, where $r=0$ or $r$ is a unit.

I have a proof by brute force. 
Suppose that such element $b$ exists.
Take $a=2$ and $a=x$. 
$$2=bq_1+r_1,$$
$$x=bq_2+r_2.$$
We already know that all the units in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are $1$ and $-1$.
Discuss all of the possible of $r_1, r_2\in \{0,\pm 1\}$ and get a contradiction.
But I don't satisfy this method. 
Is there another wise method?
Thanks!

Comment: In general, this property is not valid (at least in the form stated). Consider for example $b=1$: Then, for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have: $a=1\cdot a+0$. Similarly, we can write $a=1\cdot(a-1)+1$.

Comment: I believe he meant to write 'when $b$ is not a unit' or something to that effect.  Also note that there does exist such a (monic) $b$ when $r$ only has the restriction that $\operatorname{deg} r < \operatorname{deg} b$ (the division algorithm), so this suggests that you should look at degrees.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your comment. I had modified the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. Just show that $(2,x)=(b)$ for $r_1=r_2=0$. This means $(2,x)$ is a principal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, which is clearly a contradiction. Other cases are similar.

For example, if $r_1=1, r_2=0$, then  choose $a=3$ and there is $(2,x)=(b)$, which is a contradiction too.

For $r_1=-1, r_2=0$, prove that $(3,x)=(b)$. For $r_1=0, r_2=1$, prove that $(2,x-1)=(b)$. Both are contradiction too.

Comment: I had the idea before. 
I could show that if such $b$ exists, 
then $(b)$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.
I want to show that $(b)\subseteq (2, x)\subseteq \Bbb{Z}[x]$.
But I got stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am looking forward a method doesn't need to discuss the $r_1$ and $r_2$ case by case. (If such method exists.)